# Jboss to wildfly migration

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, datasource

i have migrating my application server from jboss 7 to wildfly 13. I have changed the standalone.xml and all the dependent files. My jboss is running with out any war file and all datasources are getting connected. But whenever i paste my project WAR file and then trying to run the application then it does not show any error but it shows some logs like:

```
2018-10-23 17:33:32,644 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.controller] (MSC service thread 1-3) CapabilityServiceSupport: Parsing ServiceName for org.wildfly.undertow.server

2018-10-23 17:33:32,652 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = VisionWeb.war_oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver_12_2

2018-10-23 17:33:32,721 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) PBOX00307: Constructing JBossPolicyConfiguration with contextID VisionWeb.war

2018-10-23 17:33:32,722 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) Cannot create permissions with 'null' metaData for id=VisionWeb.war

2018-10-23 17:33:32,804 DEBUG [io.undertow.session] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Setting default session timeout to 600000

2018-10-23 17:33:32,820 DEBUG [io.undertow.session] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Registered session listener io.undertow.servlet.core.SessionListenerBridge@734d59d

2018-10-23 17:33:33,132 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.idle.IdleRemover] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Register pool: SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@1ca68dba[pool=VisionDS] (interval=1800000)

2018-10-23 17:33:33,132 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.idle.IdleRemover] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) About to notify thread: old next: 1540297113132, new next: 1540297113132

2018-10-23 17:33:33,134 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.idle.IdleRemover] (IdleRemover) Notifying pools, interval: 900000

2018-10-23 17:33:33,136 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) VisionDS: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@21706afc[userName=dmn]) [0/30]

2018-10-23 17:33:33,137 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) Driver loaded and instance created:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver@616e3ffd

2018-10-23 17:33:33,663 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) VisionDS: returnConnection(4aeedeb, false) [0/30]

2018-10-23 17:33:33,664 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) VisionDS: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@21706afc[userName=dmn]) [0/30]

2018-10-23 17:33:33,670 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) VisionDS: returnConnection(4aeedeb, false) [0/30]

2018-10-23 17:33:33,698 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) VisionDS: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@21706afc[userName=dmn]) [0/30]

2018-10-23 17:33:33,721 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) VisionDS: returnConnection(4aeedeb, false) [0/30]

2018-10-23 17:33:33,722 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) VisionDS: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@21706afc[userName=dmn]) [0/30]

2018-10-23 17:33:33,749 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) VisionDS: returnConnection(4aeedeb, false) [0/30]
```

Comment: Are you setting and security related values in your WAR?  Can you update your question to include whats in the web.xml file?

Comment: nothing is related to security in my WAR file. and web.xml file only have listeners, servlets maapings and resource-ref.

Comment: What happens when you back up the current configuration XML you've modified, then replace it with the normal configuration?  You'll be missing the data source but possibly you have an error in your current non-working config file?

Comment: I have added the data source and the same is connecting successfully. Some of the data base queries also working and the getting the data from database but whenever it is going to create thread pool for connections it shows the above logs and then timeout.

Comment: Ahh, so it's working now 99%?  Great! When in doubt, rollback and start from square 1!  I don't think the above are errors, it's just logging in DEBUG mode.  I can tell you how to turn that off.